# read.csv() return a data frame with only variable instead of 17

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

I read into r an excel file and the output gives me a data frame with one variable V1 instead of 17 variable
the following is my code and a part of `str(read.csv.obj)`

```
bank <- read.csv('./bank.csv', skip = 1, header = F, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)
str(bank)
# 'data.frame': 4521 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ V1: chr
```

How should I get the right data frame

Comment: You probably have a different separator, not comma.

Comment: give `data.table::fread()` a try.. It is pretty good at guessing separators, and is highly customizable using it's arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that import function doesn't realize the columns correctly. It can be defferent separator, but also other characters (depends on your data).

Open your CSV in a plain text editor (like Notepad, TextEdit etc.) and check the contents.

If you see something like this:

```
12,12.3,12.8,"Europe"
...
```

it means you have

- `,` as separator
- `.` as decimal point
- `"` as quoting character

and you can use [`read.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to import this file.

---

If you see rather this:

```
12;12,3;12,8;"Europe"
...
```

it means you have

- `;` as separator
- `,` as decimal point
- `"` as quoting character

and you can use [`read.csv2()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to import this file.

---

In all other cases you can use [`read.table()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) and specify e.g.

```
read.table(file,
           sep = ";",
           dec = ".",
           quote = "'")
```